# Multiple operations in a single session in RavenDBs authorization bundle

Tags: ravendb

Ive been playing around with RavenDB quite a bit and want to use the authorization bundle to control permissions. However i am having trouble determining what the best way to compose complex code (complex as in business logic heavy) into reusable chunks while keeping the authorization intact.

For complex code i have pulled them out to a common set of methods so the code can be reused. Each one of these methods maps roughly to one authorization operation and the method itself performs its own`session.SecureFor`

However it appears `session.SecureFor` applies at session level, and only the last `SecureFor` call that is made before SaveChanges applies.

For example

```
    public void AuthorizeAndSchedule()
    {
        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            dynamic patient = new ExpandoObject();
            session.Store(patient);
            session.SetAuthorizationFor((object)patient, new DocumentAuthorization
            {
                Tags = {"Patient" }
            });


            ScheduleAppointment(session, "Authorization/Users/DrHowser", patient);
            Hospitalize(session, "Authorization/Users/DrHowser", patient);


            session.SaveChanges();
        }


    }

    protected void Hospitalize(IDocumentSession session, string requester, dynamic patient)
    {
        session.SecureFor(requester, "Hospitalization/Authorize");
        //assume other more complicated things are going on here
        patient.HospitilizationAuthorized = true;
        session.Store(patient);
    }

    protected void ScheduleAppointment(IDocumentSession session, string requester, dynamic patient)
    {
        session.SecureFor(requester, "Hospitalization/ScheduleAppointment");
        //assume other more complicated things are going on here
        patient.AppointmentScheduledFor = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        session.Store(patient);
    }
```

In the above code if Dr Howser has permission to Hospitalize but not to ScheduleAppointment this code will still succeed and the patient is scheduled for an appointment - this is because the Hospitlize has overridden any permission requirement for scheduling appointments

Are you only allowed one operation per session? If i want to perform two separate operations do i have to open up two different sessions? ... or am i just approaching this completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

The Auth bundle is meant to allow one operation per server call, yes.
Store does NOT go to the server, which is why you see the last op only is there.
Only when SaveChanges() is called do you see that.

Comment: If i do want to two operations in one go, is there issue with opening two separate sessions? or can i get away with doing a SaveChanges in between the operations?

Comment: Was savechanges enough here?